# Deriving a boundary operation from three homomorphism which compose to 0.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $C_n$, $C_{n-1}$, $C_{n-2}$, $C_{n-3}$ are modules with the homomorphisms
$$\partial_n: C_{n} \to C_{n-1}$$
$$\partial_{n-1}: C_{n-1} \to C_{n-2}$$
$$\partial_{n-2}: C_{n-2} \to C_{n-3}$$
such that 
$$\partial_{n-2} \circ \partial_{n-1} \circ \partial_{n} = 0_{n,n-3}$$
where $0_{n,n-3}: C_{n} \to C_{n-3}$ is the trivial homomorphism. I can look at the quotient groups
$$G_1 = \ker(\partial_{n-2} \circ \partial_{n-1})/\textrm{im}(\partial_{n})$$
or
$$G_2 = \ker(\partial_{n-2})/\textrm{im}(\partial_{n-1} \circ \partial_{n})$$
but I'm curious if there exists a module $M=M(\partial_{n},\partial_{n-1},\partial_{n-2})$, and two homomorphisms $L=L(\partial_{n},\partial_{n-1},\partial_{n-2})$ and $R=R(\partial_{n},\partial_{n-1},\partial_{n-2})$ such that
$$L:C_{n}\to M$$
$$R:M \to C_{n-3}$$
such that $R \circ L = 0_{n, n-3}$ and the quotient
$$G = \ker(R) / \textrm{im}(L)$$
"contains" both $G_1$ and $G_2$, yet is minimal.